# Checkbutton return value

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code, i dont see how the value is changing, it always shows PY_VAR1, by some reason. I researched a bit on the web, i cant seem to be able to find a straightforward answer on how to get the value if its pressed.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter


top = Tkinter.Tk()
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()
def test():
    print(CheckVar2)
C1 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Music", variable = CheckVar1, \
             onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, \
             width = 20)
C2 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Video", variable = CheckVar2, \
                  height=5, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,\
                 width = 20, command = test)
C1.pack()

C2.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

in the future i would need to use if statements and everything if the value is 1 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get()` will solve your problem :)

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter


top = Tkinter.Tk()
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()
def test():
    print(CheckVar2.get()) # Notice the .get()
C1 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Music", variable = CheckVar1, \
             onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, \
             width = 20)
C2 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Video", variable = CheckVar2, \
                  height=5, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,\
                 width = 20, command = test)
C1.pack()

C2.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

This prints

```
1
0
1
0
```

As i click the second box

Comment: you are the man :) thanks